# i dont get it why my billAmount value is not print on conole

Tags: javascript

```js
const billAmount = document.querySelector("#bill-amt");
const cashGiven = document.querySelector("#cash-given");

console.log(billAmount.value);
```

```html
<input type="number" id="bill-amt">

<div id="cash-given"></div>
```

Comment: You should add the corresponding HTML.

Comment: It does print the bill amount, the input's initial value is blank, and it prints a blank.  What value was you expecting it to print?

Comment: @Keith he is expecting to console.log out the value of the input when somebody enters the input

Comment: you are caling the console.log method before you even enter the input so obviously it will print out a blank value

Comment: @I_love_vegetables i enter a value but when i press ctrl+s in vscode its reset my live server and show blank on console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It prints out the vaulue, but at the load of the document. In that time the value is "". You can set many listeners but easiest one is setInterval() || setTimeout().

```
const billAmount = document.querySelector("#bill-amt");
const cashGiven = document.querySelector("#cash-given");

setInterval(outputValue,1000)

function outputValue(){
 console.log(billAmount.value)
};
```

Now it will print value every second, so when u type non-null value you should see your output in console.

Comment: ya its work but i just want a know why console.log not work sry for nob que i am new to js...